# is request (HTTP Request client) synchronous?

Tags: node.js, npm

Request is for http post and get . 
I am a newbie to node.js.

Please help me know if it is synchronous or asynchronous .
https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is asynchronous.

```
var request = require('request');
console.log('1');
request
  .get('http://google.com/img.png')
  .on('response', function(response) {
      //Happens at some time later.
      console.log('2');
      console.log(response.statusCode) // 200 
      console.log(response.headers['content-type']) // 'image/png' 
  });
console.log('3');
```

Output:

```
1
3
2
404
text/html; charset=UTF-8
```